# How to get an object instead of a list after applying groupingby on a list of Objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am doing a group by on a list of Objects as shown in the below code

```
Map<String, List<InventoryAdjustmentsModel>> buildDrawNumEquipmentMap = equipmentsAndCargoDetails.stream().
                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(InventoryAdjustmentsModel :: getBuildDrawNum));
```

Now I know the values for all the keys would have only one element, so how can I reduce it to just

```
Map<String, InventoryAdjustmentsModel>
```

instead of having to iterate through or get the 0th element for all the keys.

Comment: which object do you want? seems you look for `equipmentsAndCargoDetails.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(InventoryAdjustmentsModel::getBuildDrawNum,
                              Function.identity(),(a,b)->a));`

Comment: It works but I would like to understand What does (a,b) ->a mean?

Comment: @PeeyushPathak It's the merge lambda.  Normally it would be used to handle multiple values per key.  Since you said that each key would have only one element, it isn't really needed in your case.  In the example shown, if you make a mistake, and have multiple items for each key, it will ignore subsequent values seen for that key.  If you don't have it, you will get an error  complaining about duplicate values for the same key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the toMap collector with a merge function like this.

```
Map<String, InventoryAdjustmentsModel> resultMap = equipmentsAndCargoDetails.stream().
    collect(Collectors.toMap(InventoryAdjustmentsModel::getBuildDrawNum, 
        e -> e, (a, b) -> a));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this. By using `toMap` you can specify the `key` and the `value`. Since you said there were no duplicate keys this does not include the `merge` method.  This means you will get an error if duplicate keys are discovered.  Something I presumed you would want to know about.

```
Map<String, InventoryAdjustmentsModel> buildDrawNumEquipmentMap = 
                 equipmentsAndCargoDetails.stream().
            collect(Collectors.toMap(InventoryAdjustmentsModel::getBuildDrawNum, 
                     model->model));
```